# Google Spreadsheet Small Countif sometimes returns 0 instead of larger number

Tags: google-sheets, countif

Made a google spreadsheet for use in Eve Online for mining. Works fine most of the time, just have a little problem, that i dont understenad why is happendning.

I have the forumal *=if(max(J23,Q23)=0,0,if(max(K23:Q23)=0, SMALL(J23:Q23,COUNTIF(J23:Q23,"<=0")+1),SMALL(K23:Q23,COUNTIF(K23:Q23,"<=0")+1)))*, to try the smallest number larger then 0. this gave 0, when the numbers are the following.

{31,968.36}  {682,388.06}   {332,238.81}

Here is a link to the sheet, only set to look at it atm: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1POP4Pm7JljNDN0YQEmXNYb6DFuAZEQ3iFfTMEWx11CM/edit?usp=sharing

It can be seen under Amarr High Sec, in cell r23 and r34

Hope someone can help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that this is due to an error associated with floating point arithmetic used in spreadsheet applications. (Whether Google Sheets manages these errors as well as it could is a separate discussion.)

If you highlight cell N23 and increase the number of decimal places in the number format, you can see the result of the formula in that cell is actually 0.000000000002, and as this is the smallest number bigger than zero, your formula is returning it.

So unfortunately you need to work around the floating point errors yourself. If I'm understanding correctly, this formula could be used in R23:

`=IFERROR(MIN(FILTER(J23:Q23,ROUND(J23:Q23,2)>0)),0)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Changed in my own code, sins usning user some times gave a bit of trobles with 0, changed so that instead of looking if cell=0, i check if it is smaller then 1, did the trick.